# Check to see if css ref link is present before adding one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic

I am dynamically appending a .css file to a page. Does it matter if the .css file is already in a link? How can I check to see if the link already exists, I thought of checking in the head with javascript. Here is how I am appending the class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var AppendNewStyle = document.createElement("link");
    AppendNewStyle.setAttribute("href", "/Content/Extras.css");
    AppendNewStyle.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    AppendNewStyle.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    $('head')[0].appendChild(AppendNewStyle);
})();
</script>
```

Can I throw a check in here to see if the file is already in the head or should I just not worry about having two linked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to query for those link elements like any other element. Since you're using Jquery:

```
var allLinks = $("link");
```

Furthermore, you could use an attribute selector to find the link you care about:

```
var myLink = $('link[href="' + url +'"]');  //Find the link that matches your URL
```

If you do this in a script tag that's below where the link tag should be, you shouldn't really have any timing problems.

---

2017-04 Edit:

Template literals make this even yummier!

```
var myLink = $(`link[href="${url}"]`)
```

And for all you Jquery haters out there:

```
var myLinks = document.querySelectorAll(`link[href="${url}"]`)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a fuzzy support for the [`load` event](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/load.html) on link elements and even worse for the [`error` event](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html). Although you can load it dynamically this way, this method is not reliable.

The only reliable way to load CSS styles dynamically is via AJAX, taking advantage of the AJAX success and fail events, and add the link after a successful AJAX.

---

As for an already loaded style, you can check for all urls of all link elements and compare them to the CSS to be loaded.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link'),
    linksLen = links.length,
    i;

for(i=0;i<linksLen;i++){
    if(links[i].href.indexOf(urlToLoad) !== -1){
        //found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using simple way to check css file already exist If not then Load by providing ID to css link

```
 var cssSelector = document.getElementById("uiCss");

    // Load UI CSS file
    if (!cssSelector) {
        var filename = 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css';
        var fileref = document.createElement("link");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        fileref.setAttribute("ID", "uiCss");
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }
```